# Sumbit button showing as Textbox in a Servlet

Tags: html, servlets

I have a problem in a simple Servlet, I'm using the `response.setContentType("text/html");` to use html content, everything is good except a Submit button showing as a Textbox, I had this problem too when I was using a simple html file instead of a Servlet, I changed the html file type to HTML4 instead of HTML5 and it solved the problem, but now on the Servlet I can't do that, and I want your help about the problem that I faced when using a HTML5 file too.

Here is the code :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<HTML><BODY>");

        String identifiant = request.getParameter("identifiant");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(identifiant);

        for ( Film x : Stock.FilmList ) {
            if (x.getIdentifiant() == id) {
                out.println("Title is : "+x.getTitle()+"<BR/>");
                out.println("Nb Ex is : "+x.getNbEx()+"<BR/>");
                out.println("Autor is : "+x.getAutorPrincipal().getFirstName()+" "+x.getAutorPrincipal().getLastName()+"<BR/>");
                out.println("Genre is : "+x.getGenre());
                out.println("<form action=\"addtocart\" method=\"GET\">");
                out.println("<input type=\"text\" name=\"quantity\"/>");
                out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"idFilm\" value=\""+x.getIdentifiant()+"\"/>");
                out.println("<input type=\"sumbit\" value=\"Add\"/>");
                out.println("</form>");
            }
        }

        out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    }
```

And here an image of the result, showing the Submit button as a Textbox..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqgUs.jpg

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misspelled input type ("sumbit" is not valid input type), change:

```
<input type=\"sumbit\" value=\"Add\"/>
```

to

```
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\"/>
```

Default input type is text, so since there is no such thing as input type "sumbit" it got reversed to default "text"

Comment: Oh, that's embarrassing, I really tried hard to figure it out, thanks a lot.